# How to write lists in files with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, glob, os.path

My data is organized as such:
I have 30 folders. In each of them, 3 subfolders. In each of them, one file.

I would like to write a script that writes, in a text file 1 located in folder 1, the paths to the files located in the subfolders of this folder 1; and so on for every other folder.

The problem is that the script only writes, in each text file, the 3rd file (file in subfolder 3) rather than the files in subfolders 1, 2, 3.

This is what I tried:

```
import glob
import os

gotofolders = '/path/to/folderslocation/'
foldersname = open('/path/to/foldersname.txt').read().split()

for folders in foldersname:
    foldersdirectory = os.path.join(gotofolders,foldersname)
    filepaths = glob.glob(os.path.join(foldersdirectory)+'*subfolders/*files') 
    for filepath in filepaths:
        savethepaths = os.path.join(foldersdirectory)+'files_path_in_that_folder.txt'
        with open (savethepaths,'w') as f:
            f.write(filepath+'\n')
```

As said, it almost works, excepts that in each 'files_path_in_that_folder.txt' I have the 3rd element of the "filepath" list, rather than all 3 elements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out; I had to add:

```
with open (savethepaths,'w') as f:
    f.writelines(list("%s\n" %filepath for filepath in filepaths))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
def directory_into_file(_path, file_obj, depth): 
# depth is a string of asterisk, just for better printing. starts with empty string
file_obj.write(depth + _path + '\n')
if(os.path.isdir(_path)):
    file_list = os.listdir(_path)
    os.chdir(_path)
    for file in file_list:
        directory_into_file(file, file_obj, depth+'*')


    os.chdir("..")
```

this should work.
_path - the path of the directory,
file_obj - send the object file to the function and first,
depth - at first call send an empty string

hope this would work. didn't try it myself...